# WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, gson

I'm running a project in Eclipse (version 2019-06) which works great on my computer with java - "openjdk 1.8.0_222"

However when i try tor run the project on my other computer on Eclipse (version 2021-3) with java -"openjdk version "1.8.0_292" it doesnt work!

I get the following error:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory (file:/C:/Users/Gary/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar) to field java.lang.Throwable.detailMessage
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

It seems like there is something wrong with the settings of the newer software? Does somebody know?

How to solve this Warning messages?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself in Eclipse:

1. Right click on JRE System Library in your project listed in the package explorer in Eclipse and click on "properties"
2. Click on "Installed JREs" and "Add...". Now select "Standard VM" and click "Next"
3. Select your Directory of the newest installed JRE and type in the name. For me it was:

- JRE home: C:\Program Files (x86)\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.292.10-hotspot
- JRE name: jre-8.0.292.10-hotspot

4. Click on Finish